# Links in PDF are not recognizable while viewing it through Mobile

Tags: pdf, mobile, hyperlink

I created a PDF documents with multiple Hyperlink. I tested it in Desktop, it works perfectly in all browsers. But wile I viewed the PDF using my smart mobile, links are not working.

Mobile: HTC Wildfire, OS: Android 2.2, PDF Viewer: Adobe PDF (updated) & Quick Office

Comment: Are the links to (1) locations within the same PDF, (2) to other PDF files, (3) web addresses, or (4) something else? We found that many PDF viewers do not properly follow links to other PDF files. On iPad we only found GoodReader to work correctly in our set of linked PDF files. I am still investigating behaviors on Android.

Comment: How have you created the hyperlinks? Some PDF viewers recognize text which has the format of an URL and makes that text clickable. Other PDF viewers don's. In essence, therefore, please supply a sample PDF.